# how to maintain selenium running on jenkins server

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm having trouble maintaining selenium server running on jenkins slave. I used the following code to run selenium

```
 java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar  -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--use-gl=osmesa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /var/log/selenium/selenium.log > /var/log/selenium/output.log 2> /var/log/selenium/error.log & echo $! > /tmp/selenium.pid
```

but I keep getting issues where selenium server dies. Can someone please tell me how best to maintain selenium? What are the best practices that I should know about to maintain selenium server?

I sometimes get the following error when running selenium tests

```
tests/npw Connection refused! Is selenium server started? 

tests/npw { sessionId: null, 
status: 13, 
state: 'unhandled error', 

value: 
{ message: 'Read timed out', 
suppressed: [], 
localizedMessage: 'Read timed out', 
cause: null, 
class: 'java.net.SocketTimeoutException', 
hCode: 1232868082, 
screen: null }, 
class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
hCode: 1242507638 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is try to run the Selenium server in a Jenkins node in order to separate from other possible jobs and functionalities done by the master.
Configure it as a service and configure to run automatically at server start.

For a Centos OS:
Create a file in /etc/systemd/system/selenium-node.service

Add this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run a selenium node

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /route/to/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role node blablabla
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start selenium-node.service
```

This way it will automatically restart and will be running always.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to make sure the command is correctly.

Jenkins is just a schedule tool.If you can run the commands mantually but not when running by Jenkins, it may because of permission.